# Relative Layout align an item below and to the middle of another item

Tags: android

I am using a relative layout and want to align a TextView below and in the middle of a button as shown in the attached image. I have can get it to the bottom using BELOW, but cant figure out how to align their horizontal centers.

[image]

Comment: Put both of these in relative layout and set gravity of relative layout to center_horizontal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest way is to put  image and textview  into a relative layout

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

To do this in single Layout add `android:drawableTop`  to your TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: this looks good but I was hoping to do it without creating another relative layout.

Comment: If you want to do it in same layout use drawableTop With in TextView  Please See edit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it:

- Set the layout_width attribute to "match_parent", this way the width of the
- Then set the "gravity" attribute to "center_horizontal"

For Example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```